# Redirect to login page if user not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on wordpress site and i want to redirect visitor to login page if visitor not logged in but for some pages. I have used below code but it is not worked for me. Helped me where i am wrong in this code

```
function login_required() {
if (!is_user_logged_in() ) {

          $restricted = array(6,13,552,12,121,491,534,23,233,24,234,74,117,419); // all your restricted pages
          if ( in_array(get_the_ID(), $restricted ) ) {
            wp_redirect(home_url()); 
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'login_required');
```

Comment: you need to explain what "not worked" means here. what did it do or not do?

Comment: After adding above code in function.php file, when i hit some pages then pages not redirect to login page

Comment: and those were pages in the array `$restricted`?

Comment: yes in $restricted array define pages id

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function login_required() {
    global $post;
    $restricted = array( 6, 13, 552, 12, 121, 491, 534, 23, 233, 24, 234, 74, 117, 419 ); // all your restricted pages
    if( in_array( $post->ID, $restricted ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'login_required' );
```

Comment: not working!! your code only worked for pages not in groups pages which I had created by using buddypress

Answer (score 0):

You can use Page Restrict plugin, with this plugin you can choose an pages to require login.

See image below:

[image: Page Restrict Config]

Comment: This plugin also open the pages not redirect